# How to get a 60 Hz frequency at Logisim?

Tags: circuit-design, clock, logisim

I'm projecting a circuit at Logisim that needs a 60 Hz frequency for the clock. Looking at the Simulate tab it does not show anything like this. I even looked at the documentation, but found nothing.

How to get a 60 Hz at the tick frequency of the clock in the simulation of the circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a 60 Hz clock with the built-in components.

The simulation has an internal clock that produces "ticks". The menu "Simulate" offers you a selection of "Tick Frequency", but 60 Hz is not among them. 64 Hz is.

The component "Clock" uses "tick" as the unit for its high and low durations.

These are some options you have:

1. You do without the exact clock. Instead use any frequency you see fit for the circuit you build. For example, if you build a wall clock, let it run faster to see the hours increment without the need to wait hours.
2. You might try to use a high tick frequency and adjust the clock component to get near the 60 Hz. I tried the highest tick frequency (4.1 kHz in my case) and 19 for high and low durations. It was not exact, but quite OK.
3. Fetch the source code of Logisim, make sure that you can compile your own,  and extend or modify the selection of "Tick Frequency". While you are in the source code, check if Logisim actually is able to produce an exact tick frequency at all.
4. Learn how to write your own component, and then write such a clock component. It is not that hard, I did it once, and the introduction in the documentation is quite OK.